# Can't open Trello in IE9

Tags: trello

When I try to open Trello in IE9 on one particular computer I get this... "Your browser was unable to load all of Trello's resources. They may have been blocked by your firewall, proxy or browser configuration." I can open it fine on other computers running IE9.  I have compared privacy settings and they all seem to be the same.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You would see this if Trello was unable to load its resources from its CDN.

Try visiting

https://d2k1ftgv7pobq7.cloudfront.net/test.html

You should get a page that says

> This is a test of the [Trello](https://trello.com) CDN.

If you can't load that page, then something about your setup is interfering with resources from cloudfront.net.

Comment: I got the "This is a test of the Trello CDN" page.

Comment: @Greg: That's odd.  The JS and CSS come from the same domain, so they should work as well.  Maybe a cache issue ... Ctrl+F5?

Answer (score 0):

> **Problems, Bugs, and Crashes**
>
> If you've got a bug to report, please first check the [Trello Development board](https://trello.com/board/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c) where we maintain a list of known issues and bugs. Bugs have the red label.
>
> If you can't find the bug, are having problems with your account, or are experiencing crashes please email Fog Creek at **support@trello.com**. If you could include the browser, operating system and any errors, it will help us a bunch.

From [Trello's help page](https://trello.com/help).

Comment: When I click on the Trello Development board link above, I get the same, "Your browser was unable to load all of Trello's resources." error.  I'll try it from another computer.

Comment: @Greg then write them at `support@trello.com` explaining the problem. I'm sure they will help you.